# Let systemd use kexec as default reboot method

Tags: systemd, debian-stretch

On debian stretch with systemd, it is possible to reboot using the systemd command `systemctl kexec`.

Also, systemd handles all reboots:

```
# ls -l $(which reboot)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul  5  2017 /sbin/reboot -> /bin/systemctl
```

Because a reboot with full hardware re-initialization takes long and, more importantly, requires to input the crypto passphrase, I would rather always use kexec for reboots.

Is it possible to configure systemd in a way which uses kexec as the default `reboot` mechanism? (Apart from replacing `/sbin/reboot`)

Comment: Huh? kexec should already be used by default if you've actually staged a kernel to boot into with the `kexec` command.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace reboot for kexec**

1. Remove or rename the systemd reboot target

   rm /lib/systemd/system/reboot.target
2. Create a link to the kexec target as the reboot target

   ln -sf /etc/systemd/system/kexec.target /lib/systemd/system/reboot.target
3. Reload

   systemctl daemon-reload
4. Take note that with systemd and kexec only one way of rebooting is supported, that's using

   systemctl kexec

Rebooting via the "reboot" command does not work because the kexec-load script run via SysV init wrapper is not loading the kexec kernel unless invoked in the right way. Using kdump might no longer work.
Reference: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785714

**Cancel everything**

1. Reinstall systemd

   apt install --reinstall systemd

Comment: Is this using systemd-boot or grub? I use systemd-boot and can kexec using `systemctl kexec` but this method leaves me with a failure. I am on Ubuntu 20.10.